# Webapps "Datereverse" in Adobe Business Catalyst

Tags: web-applications

I am using older version of Adobe Business Catalyst.

Trying to use `datereverse` for sorting the list, but i can't able to do. In newer version of BC they using `sortType="DATE"` it's working fine.

Any one help to fix this problem. It's useful for me. Thank in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have find the way of adding `datereverse` to the web app. It's working for me.

```
{module_webapps,appname,a,,,,false,,true,1,datereverse}
```

Comment: Thanks @Nehemiah i have also looking for this